# Why oracle19c 1521 ort access other port, and TIME_WAIT status

Tags: oracle19c

I installed oracle19c on server 10.113.103.146,why 1521 port  access many other port on the same server ,and show TIME_WAIT status,log is:

tcp        3      0 10.113.103.146:1521     0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      119668/tnslsnr
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:18108    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:15412    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:11896    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:12708    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:15722    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:14132    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:14714    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:14928    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:15688    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:11526    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:17998    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:14918    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:13612    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:12510    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:15544    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:16644    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:17264    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:13300    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:15550    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:14474    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:11418    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:11550    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:18174    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:18218    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:13104    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:16660    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:5501     192.168.120.253:57263   ESTABLISHED 46488/ora_d000_ora1
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:17988    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:17856    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:15246    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:12704    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:14938    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:18298    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:13052    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:9998     10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:16122    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:10170    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:10010    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:12478    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:9778     10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:13816    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:17112    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:17842    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:16302    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:17592    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:16344    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:14480    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:16916    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:14004    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:17532    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:15458    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:15604    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:14944    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:17018    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:14218    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:15176    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:10534    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:11098    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:15406    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:13210    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:17708    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:12874    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:17254    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:13732    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:15142    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:11912    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:11748    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:16262    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:13916    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:18288    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:12406    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:13440    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:17704    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:10834    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:18168    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:9092     192.168.56.4:41534      ESTABLISHED 22436/java
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:14542    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:16378    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:12924    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:15874    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:15418    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:16292    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:13578    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:16886    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:18276    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:10442    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:10044    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:17464    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:16340    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:13662    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:11638    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:14370    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:18306    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:13120    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:17448    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:15112    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:10368    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:11538    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:17306    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -
tcp6       0      0 10.113.103.146:10590    10.113.103.146:1521     TIME_WAIT   -

any help?  thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Port 1521 is the server port to which the connection is made. It will always be the same. The other ports are the client-side ports, which are randomly assigned, per connection.

`TIME_WAIT` status indicates that the connection has been closed by the local host (wherever you are running netstat) but is waiting for any remaining packets to come in before completely terminating. These will time out and disappear within a few minutes. See here: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man8/netstat.8.html

```
TIME_WAIT
          The socket is waiting after close to handle packets still in the network.
```